# How to observe the list from two thread to updata data?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to test the "WaitOne", and now the conclude is correct if not display the UI, When it display the list of UI ,it's incorrect. I know that why problem on display, but I don't Know how to fix it.

When thd01 use "Application.DoEvents()", thd02 can work,but I need thread  go back thd01 continue work.

Who can tell me, how to solve this problem?

```
private void btn_Base_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thd01 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Base_thd1));
    Thread thd02 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Base_thd2));

    thd01.Start();
    thd02.Start();
} 
private void Base_thd1()
{
    if (list_Base.InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new OnUpdateListInvokeDelegate1(Base_thd1));
    }
    else
    {
        list_Base.Items.Add("Start thd1");

        Application.DoEvents();  
        list_Base.Items.Add("thd1 Sleep");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        list_Base.Items.Add("End thd1");

        list_Base.Items.Add("Set ");
        mre.Set();
    }
}

private void Base_thd2()
{
    if (list_Base.InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new OnUpdateListInvokeDelegate1(Base_thd2));
    }
    else
    {
        list_Base.Items.Add("Start thd2");
        list_Base.Items.Add("thd2 Wait...");

        mre.WaitOne()

        list_Base.Items.Add("End thd2");
}
```

I create two thread to test `WaitHandle.waitone`, 
if I don't display the UI, the correct conclude is like this.

Start thd1
thd1 sleep
Start thd2
thd2 Wait...
End thd1
thd1 Set
End thd2

When thd1 is sleep, the thd2 process keep run until `WaitOne`. 
And then thd1 wake up , 
it communicate the thd2, allow thd2 process continue to run.

It's difference if I wan to display the list of UI.It need to consider main Thread.

First I call main thread , let thd1 can display list of UI ,But it need break point,So I think use 'Application.DoEvents()' let thd2 keep running when thd1 sleep, it's work.

But it can't return thd1.

flow chart:
   `thd1   ->(OK)    thd2      ->(How to do.)       thd1`

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what you want to achieve? A bit more about order of what should happen like i.e. thread1 do operation then thread2 does some operation while Thread1 is waiting etc.

Comment: Ah, the good old `Application.DoEvents()` hack…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start a new thread, which checks if it runs in the GUI thread (by testing `.InvokeRequired()`. If that's the case (which always will be in the first call) you call `BeginInvoke()` which will queues to call your method on the GUI thread. Then when your method will be called a second time within the GUI thread you test again if you are on the correct thread and if yes (which will now be), you start adding items to the list **from within the GUI thread**.

That means, your `Thread.Sleep()` and filling of the list will be called within your GUI thread. All your created threads will do is forwarding the call to the GUI thread and exit.

Just for a first mock, you should rewrite your method to something like this:

```
private void Base_thd1()
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => list_Base.Items.Add("Start thd1")));
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => list_Base.Items.Add("End thd1")));
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => list_Base.Items.Add("Set ")));
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => mre.Set()));
}
```

Maybe you should take a look at the [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx). It runs code in a different thread and you can within that method call `ReportProgress()`, which will execute the method attached to `ProgressChanged` in GUI thread. Also after the method has finished it calls the method attached to `RunWorkerCompleted` also within the GUI thread.